# enumeration yielded no result in mysql with c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm writing a poco generator for mysql for generating php/c# scripts for a schoolproject and the problem I am having is that when i execute a query the enumeration (in the reader) keeps yielding no results, but when i execute the exact same query directly in phpmyadmin it runs just fine.

this is my code:

```
#region Get table names

    public void getTablesFromDatabase()
    {
        Tables[0] = new List<string>();
        MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

        command.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '{DB}'";

        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Tables[0].Add(reader["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
        }

    }

    #endregion
```

the connection is opened and set outside the method for convinience sake.

if anyone could help me it would very much be appreciated, if you need more info about the code fire away, im not great at asking questions.

Comment: are you connecting to the correct database? Are you using credentials with the same privilegues as you use for log-in into phpMyAdmin? are other primitive Select statements working correctly when you call them using this code?

Comment: The connectionstring is correct, i am running it on my localhost with the root user and it has full privilegues to the database, other statements such as the connectionstring for first setup works, after that you select a database and the connection string gets correctly updated

Comment: If you try replacing the SQL statement in the code above with some simple SQL that selects data from the table (not information schema), does it work?

Comment: first sorry for my late reply i have been busy with other important things, i've replaced the query but it still says it doesn't have results. however when i dive into the debug function and look at the non public members -> resultset all the data is present. but i cant seem to read it